# Filter youtube search results for a specific keyword based on the video categories

Tags: asp.net, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have implemented a code to search youtube videos matching to a particular keyword and show those videos on my site using the youtube-v3-api .
I want to filter out those videos on the basis of categories which are mentioned by youtube already. I am coding in asp.net and have successfully got the youtube videos on my site, just want to know how to filter those search results on the basis of categories.

Comment: Welcome to stack in order to help you we need to see what you are doing.   Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score -1):

Normally you can specify a categoryId when performing a YouTube API search, but it only accepts one categoryId. It sounds like you want to exclude multiple categories from the video results.

Well, if you've already used videos:list to get YouTube videos, the snippet returned contains the categoryId for each video.

You can then make a request to get all [YouTube VideoCategories](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list#request) and filter out the categoryIds from the categories you don't want.